# Why are flutter commands not returning any results?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I tried to run flutter after a few months and the commands are not working anymore.
They are not showing any error or anything at all. I am using windows 11.
I just reinstalled flutter again and still no result, I added it again to environment variables and one time in showed that it is unable to find git in your path while I tried to open a new project . can anyone please tell me what to do

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what do you get if you run the commands using a different terminal than VS Code's integrated terminal?